# Como alinhar 7 elementos na mesma linha?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou desenvolvendo este site em bootstrap http://raissafigueiredo.com.br/masterclinic/

Porém, lá embaixo na parte de especialidades, tenho 7 elementos na mesma linha. Tive que usar uma "gambiarra técnica" para alinha-los, pois não encontrei uma classe especifica que comporte os 7 na mesma linha. Na versão desktop fica tudo bem, porém na versão mobile os elementos ficam alinhados a esquerda e desorganizados.

Segue abaixo meu código:

```
<div class="feature-box">
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-center wow fadeInUp animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;" data-wow-animation-name="fadeInUp">
          <div class="feature-box-heading">
            <em>
                <img width="59" height="55" alt="" src="img/icon-botox.png">
            </em>
            <h4>Botox e DTM</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-center wow fadeInUp animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;" data-wow-animation-name="fadeInUp">
          <div class="feature-box-heading">
            <em>
                <img width="41" height="55" alt="" src="img/icon-clareamento.png">
            </em>
            <h4>Clareamento</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-center wow fadeInUp animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;" data-wow-animation-name="fadeInUp">
          <div class="feature-box-heading">
            <em>
                <img width="50" height="55" alt="" src="img/icon-implantes.png">
            </em>
            <h4>
              Implantes
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-center wow fadeInUp animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;" data-wow-animation-name="fadeInUp">
          <div class="feature-box-heading">
            <em>
                <img width="50" height="55" alt="" src="img/icon-estetica.png">
            </em>
            <h4>
              Estética
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-center wow fadeInUp animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;" data-wow-animation-name="fadeInUp">
          <div class="feature-box-heading">
            <em>
                <img width="50" height="55" alt="" src="img/icon-odontologia.png">
            </em>
            <h4>
              Odontologia
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-center wow fadeInUp animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;" data-wow-animation-name="fadeInUp">
          <div class="feature-box-heading">
            <em>
                <img width="50" height="55" alt="" src="img/icon-canal.png">
            </em>
            <h4>
              Tratamento de Canal e Ronco
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-center wow fadeInUp animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInUp;" data-wow-animation-name="fadeInUp">
          <div class="feature-box-heading">
            <em>
                <img width="38" height="55" alt="" src="img/icon-proteses.png">
            </em>
            <h4>
              Próteses
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Editei a porcentagem para que os elementos se comportem na mesma linha sem quebrar.

```
#home-especialiadade .col-sm-2 {
    width: 14.2%;
}
```

Comment: Marcelo, seja bem vindo ao SOpt! Explique melhor, quais elementos você precisa alinhar? O que já tentou? Edite a pergunta e insira o código que já tem, será mais fácil para alguem ajudá-lo.

Comment: Obrigado Mauricio. Editei e coloquei os códigos.

Comment: O Bootstrap tem um sistema de grid que pode te ajudar nisso. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode adicionar a classe `col-xs-12`, porém tem que corrigir pois a sua classe `#home-especialiadade .col-sm-2` esta sobrebondo ela.

Adiona `media query` para sua classe `#home-especialdiade .col-sm-2`:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    #home-especialiadade .col-sm-2 {
        width: 14.2%;
    }
}
```

Para resolver o seu problema de 7 colunas você pode ver essa resposta no [SO Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955088/7-equal-columns-in-bootstrap)

Comment: Só para o pessoal entender: `100/7 = 14.285714285714286`

Answer (score 5):

Existe uma maneira simples de fazer isso com a função `calc` do css.

```
.minhas-colunas{
    width: calc(100% / 7);
}
```

Para garantir que valores do `padding` não atrapalhem no cálculo, costumo utilizar `box-sizing:border-box`, que calculará o tamanho do elemento literalmente, incluindo o tamanho do `border` e `padding`.

```
.minhas-colunas {
    width: calc(100%/7);
    padding:5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;/** o padding não vai atrapalhar **/
  }
```

E por fim, utilize o famoso `float:left`:

```css
.minhas-colunas{  
  width: calc(100%/7);
  background-color: green;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  float:left;
  display:block;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.pai{
 width:500px;
 background:blue;
 padding:10px
}

.pai:after{
  clear:both;
  content: ' ';
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
    <div class="minhas-colunas">
    1
    </div>
    <div class="minhas-colunas">
    2
    </div>
    <div class="minhas-colunas">
    3
    </div>
    <div class="minhas-colunas">
    4
    </div>
    <div class="minhas-colunas">
    5
    </div>
    <div class="minhas-colunas">
    6
    </div>
    <div class="minhas-colunas">
    7
    </div>
  <div class="minhas-colunas">
    1
    </div>
    <div class="minhas-colunas">
    2
    </div>
    <div class="minhas-colunas">
    3
    </div>
    <div class="minhas-colunas">
    4
    </div>
    <div class="minhas-colunas">
    5
    </div>
    <div class="minhas-colunas">
    6
    </div>
    <div class="minhas-colunas">
    7
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Essa função é a solução para meus problemas! Hahah, apesar de (pelo menos por mim) ser raramente vista por aí...

Comment: Dei  um tapa na resposta

Answer (score 1):

Um outro método sem necessidade de especificar qualquer largura (exceto para configuração mobile, se desejar), seria utilizar um ul li com `display:table-cell`.

```
ul {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
ul li {
    display:table-cell
}
```

Veja este meu exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/4r8mwLap/1/

Obs.: No exemplo o código está funcional com a opção de responsive.

#### Editado

Se desejar continuar usando `div` ao invés de `ul li`, o processo é o mesmo, basta utilizar as mesmas propriedades em `divs`, veja o exemplo atualizado: http://jsfiddle.net/4r8mwLap/2/

O bloco de baixo é com estrutura em div usando as mesmas propriedades do ul li.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar [***flexbox***](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) <sup>[*suporte*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)</sup>:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</section>
```